# go: how to abstract queue message fetch with an interface for mocking and testing, with channel return type?

Tags: unit-testing, go, nats.io

I'm using a NATS JetStream backend as a work queue, but I'm now trying to write an interface that supports common queue methods like `publish` and `fetch`, to come up with a mockable and testable solution that will also allow me to switch to a different queue/stream backend if need be:

```golang
type QueueLayer interface {
    // Publish publishes a message to the queue
    Publish(ctx context.Context, subject string, payload []byte) (string, error)
    // Fetch returns a channel of X prefetched messages from the queue
    Fetch(prefetch int) (<-chan any, error)
}

type Stream struct {
    conn           JetStreamConnection
    stream         jetstream.Stream
    taskConsumer   jetstream.Consumer
    resultConsumer jetstream.Consumer
}

...

func fetch(q QueueLayer, prefetch int) (<-chan any, error) {
    return q.Fetch(prefetch)
}

func main() {
...
    // mystream is a concrete type of Stream, which embeds the NATS JetStream connection, stream, consumers, etc. as above
    mystream := NewStream(...)

    fetch(mystream, *prefetch) // ERROR!
...

}
```

Since NATS' `fetch` returns a read-only channel of JetStream messages (`<-chan jetstream.Msg`), I thought maybe the empty interface `<-chan any` channel for the interface return type would allow me to satisfy the interface when passing a concrete type, but no cigar:

```
cannot use mystream (variable of type Stream) as QueueLayer value in argument to fetch: Stream does not implement QueueLayer (wrong type for method Fetch)
        have Fetch(int) (<-chan jetstream.Msg, error)
        want Fetch(int) (<-chan any, error)compilerInvalidIfaceAssign
var mystream Stream
```

Hm, so even if literally any type will usually satisfy the empty interface, this is not the case here for my own interface, due to Go not supporting [covariant types](https://go.dev/doc/faq#covariant_types), right?

How does one solve this in an idiomatic way?

Comment: 'have Fetch(int) (<-chan jetstream.Msg, error)
want Fetch(int) (<-chan any, error)compilerInvalidIfaceAssign' says everything

Comment: I do understand what the error message points out, unfortunately it doesn't help me in guiding me to fix this in an idiomatic way. If return types have to match verbatim for the interface to be met, how would one align them best across different concrete implementations?